# Is there a limit for Javascript (continous loop) runtime?

Tags: javascript, html, chromium

I'm working on a digital signage/indoor media system based on HTML5/CSS3 instead of Flash. It works with separated modules (weather, twitter, news, photos, videos etc.) and that's how I run:

- The main (controller) function is called when the system runs
- This function receives from a PHP the list of all installed modules
- This function calls the first of the modules (the modules are all functions in separated files)
- The module function does all it must do (show images or whatever) and, once it finished, it calls a callback function.
- The callback function calls the main (controller) function again, that calls the second module and so on
- ...
- When the last module finishes its tasks, the main (controller) function calls again the first function. And *so on*.

It will run in a server-ready computer and some big displays 24 hours per day, 7 days per week, with no time to rest, in a Chromium fullscreen window. All the modules must do "in time" requests, so the administrators can add or remove new images, the news and weather systems can work... without refreshing the window. All the timers (to change between modules, images etc.) are made with setInterval().

Yesterday morning it started running. The computer is never turned off, but I noticed this morning that the system frozen in one of the modules, after about 24 hours up. I refreshed the app and it's ok. Since the server is also used for many other company tasks, I don't know if it is due to some memory problem or really the Javascript limitation.

**My question is:** is there some limit time that the Javascript continuously? Or it can run for hours/days/weeks without any problem?

Comment: I don't think most JS runtimes "need a rest". I'd look to your code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main limit will be memory leaks slowly eating away your memory. Other then that there's no real reason.

Comment: So I should add another timer to auto refresh the page on every X hours?

Comment: Auto-refreshing is not guaranteed to work. Browsers don't always free the memory used by the page. 

A better solution would be to simple make sure there's no memory leaks in your website.

Comment: Thanks! I found out the problem is a bit more stupid. Just the unstable internet :P I solved it by creating a cache system on the server side.

Comment: Hi Jefrey, can you please elaborate on your exact problem and the solution you found using caching on server?